# Parse html element in a string using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am working in django project in which some data in database are rendered using jquery on page load. The response from jquery is in json format and this json object have values like:

```
'Hi <b>User</b><br> How are you?'
```

I would like jquery to parse this string so that it is displayed correctly.ie

Hi **User** 
How are you?

I tried $.parseHTML and DOMParser but its not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "not working" entail? errors? invalid results?

Comment: $("#MyDiv").html($.parseHTML('Hi <b>User</b><br> How are you?' )) .Should work.Then what is not working for you.'How are you' will come in the second line.Not as you are expecting all will come in same line as there is a <br> tag if you want all should come in same line then $("#MyDiv").html($.parseHTML( ('Hi <b>User</b><br> How are you?').replace("<br>","  ") ))

Comment: Not working means the text is being displayed as '[object Text],[object HTMLBRElement],[object HTMLBRElement],[object Text]..'. The data I am parsing is the jquery ajax response in json format. For eg: response.text = 'Hi <b>User</b><br> How are you?'

Answer (score 0):

`$parsed = $('<div>').html('Hi <b>User</b><br> How are you?' )` works well.

If you want to use only `'Hi <b>User</b><br> How are you?'`, you should append $parsed to where you want it put and run `$parsed.find('b').unwrap()`.